# Using result of useSelector() in component

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-redux

I am using react-redux to manage state and axios to make API calls.

My default state:

```
const defaultState = {
    isLoading: true,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    authUser: {}
}
```

`isLoading` and `authUser` are both updated once the API's login call has ran successfully. Nothing wrong here.

In a userProfile component, I am using the following to get the logged in user's ID from the store:

```
const authUser = useSelector(state => state.authentication.authUser);

const user = users.getUser(authUser.id);
console.log(authUser);
```

`authUser` is always empty on page load but a split second late, it prints again, this time with the state contents.

I have the userProfile component behind a custom `PrivateRoute` component:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const authentication = useSelector(state => state.authentication);
    
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props =>
                authentication.isAuthenticated ? (
                    <Component {...props} />
                ) : (
                    authentication.isLoading ? 'loading...' :
                        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
                )
            }
        />
    )
};
```

The `loading...` text shows before the component catches up, then the 2 console logs appear one after the other. The first empty, the second with data.

What am I missing here? This async stuff is driving me insane!

Answer (score 0):

---

with this implementation of private route u can save current path of user and let user continue his process after login again

```
import React from 'react';
import { Login } from '../../pageComponents';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const PrivateRoute = (Component) => {
const Auth = (props) => {
    const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    // Login data added to props via redux-store (or use react context for example)
    // If user is not logged in, return login componentc
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return <Login />;
    }
    // If user is logged in, return original component
    return <Component {...props} />;
};

// Copy getInitial props so it will run as well
if (Component.getInitialProps) {
    Auth.getInitialProps = Component.getInitialProps;
}

return Auth;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

---

then user it every page you want Private Rout like below

```
const myPrivateRoute = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
     )
}

export default PrivateRoute(myPrivateRoute)
```

Comment: The reason I have it the way I do is so that the user doesn't have to log in again with every page refresh. That would be a poor user experience

Answer (score 0):

---

so create component like this and load your last section from local storage or cookie then validate and send into your redux store then you can memorize log

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";
import * as globalActions from "../../../store/actions/globalAction";
import * as userAction from "../../../store/actions/userAction";
const StorageManagment = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
/* ----------------------------------- listening to token changes ----------------------------------- */

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(userAction.loadCart());
}, []);
useEffect(async () => {
    try {
        if (window)
            await checkLocalDataWithRedux()
                .then((data) => {
                    const { userDTO, token } = data;
                    dispatch(userAction.loginUser(token, userDTO));
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                    dispatch(userAction.logOutUser());
                });
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}, []);

function checkLocalDataWithRedux() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            /* -------- read user data from localStorage and set into redux store ------- */
            const { userDTO, token } = localStorage;
            if (userDTO && token) {
                resolve({ token: token, userDTO: JSON.parse(userDTO) });
            } else logOutUser();
        } catch (e) {
            reject();
        }
    });
}

function logOutUser() {
    dispatch(userAction.logOutUser());
}

return null;
};

export default StorageManagment;
```

---

then load it in your app.jsx file

app.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <ErrorBoundary>
                    <StorageManagment />
                    <DefaultLayout>
                        <Application {...this.props} />
                    </DefaultLayout>
                </ErrorBoundary>
            </Provider>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Comment: I'm  not sure you understand correctly... The only things I have in local storage are a jwt token and refresh token. Since the store is emptied on refresh, I use the refresh token to generate a new token and also get the user ID. When visiting the UserProfile page, I us the user ID and token to make a call to the API and fetch the user info. This is then displayed throughout the component. Your suggestion doesn't seem to help with this.